# React onSubmit event not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When I hit enter on the form, it does not trigger the onSubmit event. There are no errors. The other event, onBlur, does dispatch. The logForm function will eventually console.log a JSON string of all the form's fields, but I have not yet gotten that far. I am simply trying to trigger the onSubmit event on the form. Any help or explanation would be appreciated.
Here's the code:

```
import React from 'react'

export default function SignupForm() {
  return (
    <form onSubmit={logForm}>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label>
          Name:
          <input onBlur={logUpdate} className="form-control" 
          type="text" placeholder="Username"/>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label>
          Email:
          <input onBlur={logUpdate} className="form-control" 
          type="text" placeholder="johndoe@example.com"/>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label>
          Password:
          <input onBlur={logUpdate} className="form-control" 
          type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
        </label>
      </div>
      <div className="form-group">
        <label>
          Confirm Password:
          <input onBlur={logUpdate} className="form-control" 
          type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
        </label>
      </div>
    </form>
  )
}

function logForm(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  const formInfo = new FormData(e.target)
  console.log(formInfo)
}

function logUpdate(e) {
  console.log(e.target.value)
}
```

Comment: You form does not have a button so it will not submit the form

Comment: I thought onSubmit works when you hit the 'enter' key?

Comment: the enter key does not, by default, submit. As @TryingToImprove wrote, try including a button at the bottom of your form, that would do the trick too.

Comment: Thank you that fixed my issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is put an `onKeyPressed` event on your form controls like so

`onKeyPress={this.onKeyPressed}`

and then have a function catching the `onKeyPressed`

```
onKeyPressed: function (e) {
    if (e.key === "Enter") {
        logForm(e);
    }
}
```

If you want `Submit` to work, add a button to your html section: (Credit to @TryingToImprove)

```
  <div className="form-group">
    <label>
      <button className="btn btn-default" type="submit">submit form</button>
    </label>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! But I have to use onSubmit.

Comment: @Tikkes when you add the comment "include a button at the bottom" to your answer it will contain the complete solution for this problem :)

Comment: Thanks for credit :) But do `type="submit"` instead of `onClick={logForm}` for getting the `<form onSubmit={]>` to play nice with enter-key.. :)

Comment: Thanks @TryingToImprove